# How to access Dictionary<string, object> in order to instaniate another object?

Tags: c#, .net, object

I'm returning a dictionary that has a list of return values, in this case being an object. I'm trying to access this object to create a model based on the objects data.

I have tried the dot operator.

```
 Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "key",  new Object { id  = 123 } }
                };
    
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dict){
        kvp.id //doesn't work
    }
```

How do I get that `id` value?

Comment: you need to declare a type with a property (prefered) or fields with that name.

Comment: I would not expect `new Object { id  = 123 }` to compile. Is this dictionary going to contain objects of the same type?

Comment: Either declare a class or struct having the properties you need or assign the values directly to the dictionary. `new Dictionary<string, object>(){
    { "number",  123 },
    { "text",  "hello" },
};`

Comment: Are you trying to return a object from the dictionary when a key is found?

Answer (score 2):

The type `System.Object` whose C# alias is `object` is the base of all inheritance hierarchies. Every .NET type derives from it and is assignment compatible to it. However, `object` has no fields or properties. If you want to access fields or properties from objects statically typed as `object`, you must cast them to a deriving type containing these members. Example:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Let's create an instances of this class and assign it to variables:

```
Person p = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Miller" };
object o = new Person { FirstName = "Tina", LastName = "Smith" };

Console.WriteLine(p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName); // OK

Console.WriteLine(o.FirstName + " " + o.LastName); // DOES NOT WORK

// but

if (o is Person p2) {
    Console.WriteLine(p2.FirstName + " " + p2.LastName); // OK
}

// or

Console.WriteLine(((Person)o).FirstName + " " + ((Person)o).LastName); // OK
```

---

You cannot create an object with `new Object { id  = 123 }`, since `System.Object` does not have a field or property `id`.

You could create an object of an anonymous type like this `object o2 = new { id  = 123 };` however, since its type is anonymous, you don't have a type name that you could use for casting. You will not be able to access `id`. What is an anonymous type good for then? Well, it's limited to temporary use inside a method. E.g. you can use the `var` keyword and let C# infer the type of the variable: `var a = new { id  = 123 };`. The variable is still strongly typed and the type is determined at compile time, even if you don't know the type name. And you can access the property `a.Id`.

---

With a `Dictionary<string, object> dict`, you can either assign simple values directly:

```
dict.Add("n", 123);
dict.Add("t", "xyz");
dict.Add("d", DateTime.Now);
```

or, if you want an object with properties, declare a class or struct with these properties.

```
public class TextBlock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override ToString() => $"Text block {Id} = {Text}";
}
```

and assign it like this

```
dict.Add("key", new TextBlock{ Id = 123, Text = "hello" });
```

Now you can print this object directly

```
Console.WriteLine(dict["key"]);
```

`Console.WriteLine` uses the overridden `ToString` method to get a text representation of the object.

Or you can cast the value to access the properties

```
Console.WriteLine( ((TextBlock)dict["key"]).Text );
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure how the line below is going to work

```
{ "key",  new Object { id  = 123 } }
```

`new Object` and then parameter `id`

This is what I suggest

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
     { "key",  new { id  = 123 } }//using dynamic
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dict)
{
    var theObject = kvp.Value;
}
```

Comment: This is not a dynamic, it is an anonymous type which is fully declared (implicitly) at compile time.

Comment: either ways, annonymous type or object. I just don't see that instantiation working

Comment: Note that when you assign an anonymous type to `object`, later, you will not be able to cast it to this anonymous type (because you don't have a type name) to access its properties. An anonymous type is only for temporary usage inside a method. You can assign it to `var` and don't lose the type information.